# How to customize the look & feel of the google classroom share button

Tags: google-classroom

Currently, it appears like a square with no text beside, we want to customize the look & feel without disturbing the icon of course to match our other buttons.

Already tried adding styles to the `div` which is converted to the share icon, but unsuccessful so far.

```
<div id='widget-div' class='btn btn-blue'>Google Classroom</div>
```

The above line renders as below :

[image]

Any idea how to proceed further or which direction to look into ?

Comment: Did you check this link https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton which has sample on customizing classroom share button.

Comment: yeah, went through it, but all I could find is that it allows to change to 3 predefined colors and sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a completely different share button you will need to write your own JS to style the button correctly, handle the mouse click, etc., and then direct the user to a URL of the form https://classroom.google.com/share?url=https://foo.com/ ([source](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/enhancements-to-classroom-share-button.html)). (You'll need to following the [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/classroom/brand) too.)

Comment: Google's blog post doesn't mention this, but `https://foo.com/` should probably be encoded/escaped.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the button you can refer to the [Share button](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton) documentation. However, there are some restrictions that you would need to follow to modify the Classroom button in the appropriate way.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/brand) you can find all the specifications and restrictions to the logo. Check if these specifications allow you to modify the logo accordingly to your needs.

Comment: have already gone through, but couldn't find any way to customize the way I want (please refer the snapshot in the question). All it allows is change to 3 predefined colors and sizes. Please see the updated question on what type of customization I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the white logo (square or circle) on a colored background of your choice. Full brand guidelines [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/brand)