# How can I use the round logo for the Google Classroom Share Button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-classroom

I want to use the round logo of the Google Classroom Share Button as shown in the "[Google Classroom Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/classroom/brand)" page.

I've used the example in the "[Add a Classroom Share Button](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton)" page, but I can't figure out how to use the round logo instead of the square one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What are you trying to add it to? A webpage? with JavaScript?

Comment: Just trying to run the example from the Google Classroom example page, but using the round logo instead of the square one.
I thought maybe there's a data attribute that I can use to specify the logo shape, but couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Tag the question with the language you are using. It'll get your question viewed by the appropriate audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "configure" the share button itself to use a different logo; to accomplish this you'll need to ["manually" display the icon and then direct the user to the REST share endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460865/11543).

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS` to change the icon.

Download the round icons package: https://developers.google.com/classroom/assets/classroom_circle_logo.zip

Upload the icon you want somewhere online an overwrite the `background-image`-rule

When using the example code I get e `CSS` rule like:

```
.mgQYsb {
    background-image: url("https://www.gstatic.com/classroom/logo_square_48.svg");
}
```

overwrite this rule with

```
.mgQYsb {
    background-image: url("<your url>/<your logo>") !important;
}
```

And let's hope the class stays the same. Or you might find a more general rule which does not take the class into account like

```
div.hrIdWidgetContainer>div>div> {
    background-image: url("<your url>/<your logo>") !important;
}
```

I tried to play around with the actual rule to see if the round logo is somewhere in the same folder on gstatic.com, but did not find anything.