# Google Classroom website integration link

Tags: google-classroom

I have successfully added the Google Classroom code to my website to share a URL using Google Classroom. The code makes the Google Classroom icon into a link that pops up the GC sharing information. What I want to do is have the "Google Classroom" text I place next to it also function as the same sort of link.

If I place text inside the g:sharetoclassroom tag, it gets overridden by the icon. But I don't know how to make the text I place next to it "live" as well.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the GC button you will need to handle it yourself.  See the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460865/6902644).